# NEXTJS and Supabase, Image security

Tags: next.js, supabase

how can I deny access of an Image URL only outside of my WEB application.
When i put the Image storage and copy that in new window of chrome for example, It should be not appear.
How can I implement that.

I tried to use createSignedUrl() but with no result.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to prevent images from being displayed only within your application. That is why you should protect your data properly using RLS and signed URLs. You can read about how to setup RLS on your Supabase storage [here](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/storage/security/access-control).

You should set your expiration time for the signed URL as short as needed to display the image. That way, if someone with bad intent obtains the URL of your image, the URL is already expired, and they cannot view the image.

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation,Could you please, show me or give documentation to configure RLS and signed URL, I want to precise that I am using <Image /> next component to show the image so I use supabase-image-loader, to just say that image url should be signed in supagvase-image-loader to get the entire url.

Comment: @ManoloRajaonah Sure, here you can find docs on how to setup RLS on Supabase storage. https://supabase.com/docs/guides/storage/security/access-control

Comment: Also, it seems like you are using a public bucket, but why do you care how people view your image?

Answer (score 0):

```
'use client';

interface ISupabaseLoaderParams {
  src: string;
  width: number;
  quality?: number;
}

const bucketName: string = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BUCKET_NAME || '';

export default function supabaseLoader({
  src,
  width,
  quality,
}: ISupabaseLoaderParams) {
  const url = new URL(
    `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_URL}/storage/v1/object/public/${bucketName}/${src}`,
  );
  url.searchParams.set('width', width.toString());
  url.searchParams.set('quality', (quality || 75).toString());

  return url.href;
}
```

Here is my code, how to sign this Image

Comment: Instead of posting this as an answer, you should edit your original question and add this info.